# linux "perf annotate" tool is reading file using mmap()/munmap() in 400 byte chunks

Tags: linux, centos, perf

Accordingly this never finishes for real world data.

Anybody any clue if one can convince the tool to forget its 16bit heritage?

yes -- this applies to

CentOS release 6.5 (Final)

Comment: What 16-bit heritage?  `perf` is a Linux tool, and Linux has 32-bit x86 heritage, not 16.  What real world tasks "never finish" for you?

Comment: This was a joke because why otherwise would they read a file in 400byte chunks taking ages to do it.

Comment: Can you post fragment of strace output? Something like `strace -tttT perf annotate ...`, not the head of file but several dozens lines from middle with many mmap/munmap. Part of implementation is in https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v5.4/source/tools/perf/builtin-annotate.c and https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v5.4/source/tools/perf/util/annotate.c files. What is size of your perf.data file, of your binary? How did you collect the samples?